# What guard should I use in Spatie permission when I'm using sanctum for my APIs?

Tags: laravel, permissions, roles

I'm currently using the [Spatie permission package](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/basic-usage), but I'm a bit confused what guard should I use since I'm using sanctum to authenticate the users. Should I use `web`? or `api`? or `sanctum`?

Answer (score -1):

you can use the api guard if you have configured the api guard with sanctum driver in auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'sanctum',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ]
],
```

and in api.php you can group them with

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
```